# Azure AppInsights working with my one instrumentation key but not with other

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have two separate subscriptions (I) Development Subscription (II) Production Subscription.

I have implemented App Insights for my Development Subscription. I have added latest NUGET Packages (1.0) and implemented javascript code snippet in _Layout page of MVC (before  tag) as well.

Using some reference article of MSDN, I have make the instrumentation key dynamically (through App Settings, I am reading my key and under Global.asax I am giving that key to Telemetry.Active Session

> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey
>   = ApplicationInsightsConfigSettings.InstrumentationKey;
>
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.ContextInitializers.Add(new
>   ApplicationContextInitializer());

Now, in Development Subscription AppInsights is giving me all page, session information along with Call Stack for any exception.

But for Production Subscription though I have used correct Instrumentation Key, It is showing "No Data in this time period". I have waited almost 24 Hours after configuring and publishing the last build on this server.

Can anyone suggest what should I check to troubleshoot more here?

Comment: For your production subscription are you seeing any data at all, for example are you also sending your client-side telemetry to your production subscription? which means you would have to dynamically decide what instrumentation key to use in your JavaScript snippet. Is there a publicly facing website page that you can point it - then we can investigate the client-side telemetry. To investigate why server-side telemetry is not getting sent, can you please use Fiddler to see what data is getting sent to dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track from your IIS (w3wp) process as you browse your app.

Comment: is your javascript code also reading the instrumentation key?  by default, it doesn't do that, it would have the key embedded right in the javascript snippet.  so verify that the snippet is also reading your active key, instead of your development one.